# Listview Imageview loading animation XMPP smack

Tags: android

i'm using smack for my chat application on android. all works fine.
now i've no idea how to display the progressbar on my imageview while the image is downloading.

i'm using a custom listview adapter with 2 layouts (message, image)
when i receive a file i insert the filepath, filename into my sqlite db and nothify the adapter that the data has changed.
now i've no idea how to refresh the imageview in the listview again when the download is complete to show the image. (i want only to change the imageview on download complete and not update all listview items again)

the problem is that i've no listitem view / id of the view which the adapter has created.

thanks

*EDIT*

```
public class messagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<messages> {
    private ArrayList<messages> objects;
    public messagesAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<messages> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (type == 1 || type == 0)
        {
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null);
            }

            messages i = objects.get(position);

            if (i != null) {

                ImageView ivProfileLeft = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivProfileLeft);
                ImageView ivProfileRight = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivProfileRight);
                TextView tvBody = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);

                if (i.getmessagefrom().equals(ConnectionHolder.getmyusername()))
                {
                    ivProfileLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ivProfileRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (i.getmessageto().equals(ConnectionHolder.getmyusername()))
                {
                    ivProfileRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ivProfileLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                tvBody.setText(i.getmessage());
            }
        } else if (type == 2)
        {
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_picture, null);
            }

            final messages i = objects.get(position);

            if (i != null) {

                ImageView ivpic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivpic);
                ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                TextView tvbody = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvbody);
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.getlocation());
                ivpic.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                ivpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        File tmp = new File(i.getlocation());
                        Uri tmpuri = Uri.fromFile(tmp);
                        String lalal = i.getlocation();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(i.getlocation());
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(i.getlocation())),"image/*");
                        getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                tvbody.setText(i.getmessage());
            }
        }

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (objects.get(position).type == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        } else if (objects.get(position).type == 2)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide your adapter code so that i can understand your logic

Comment: added adapter code! thx for your help!!!